# A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php

```
$f='f';
for ($i=128; $i>0; $i=$i/2)
if ($f & $i) echo "1";
else echo "0";
```

Нужно проверить каждый бит символа для вывода его битового представления. Но появляется куча ошибок A non-numeric value encountered, хотя я проверяю всего 8 бит.

Comment: попробуй заменить 'f' на 102. PHP это не C/C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как уже заметил Ипатьев, в вашем коде есть две ошибки. Строка `'f'` преобразуется к числу неправильным образом. По умолчанию используются стандартные правила PHP, вам же нужно получить числовое представление байта с помощью функции [ord](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.ord.php).

Вторая ошибка кроется в неверном условии цикла. Попытайтесь выполнить код вручную на бумажечке, и вы увидете, что когда $i доходит до 1, то `1 / 2 == 0.5`, а это больше нуля. С математической точки зрения цикл получился бы бесконечным. Но в реальности это не так, потому что точность чисел в машинном представлении ограничена, и в какой-то момент после деления получается ноль.

И да, если вы хотите научится и стать настоящим программистом, пожалуйста, форматируйте ваш код. Используйте отступы для тела цикла и условий, ставьте пробелы вокруг бинарных операторов (присваивание, деление, сравнение и т.п.) Чтобы узнать об этом подробнее, можете прочитать [PEAR Coding Standards](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php), где описывается рекомендуемый стиль кода.

---

```
$f = 'f';
for ($i = 128; $i >= 1; $i = $i / 2) {
    if (ord($f) & $i) {
        echo "1";
    } else {
        echo "0";
    }
}
```

Внесённые изменения я выделил жирным.

Кстати говоря, алгоритм для перевода чисел в битовое представление уже реализован функцией [decbin](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.decbin.php).

```
$f = 'f';
echo decbin(ord($f));
```

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка совершенно очевидная. В математических операциях могут участвовать только *числа*. Поэтому *символ* "f" сначала преобразуется в число по правилам РНР (и становится равным нулю), но при этом РНР совершенно справедливо сообщает тебе, что ты пытаешься совершить математическую операцию с значением, которое не является числом.

На уроке надо было не рубиться в доту, а слушать преподавателя. Тогда бы ты не пропустил функцию ord().

А вот почему ты проверяешь не 8 бит, а чуть больше тысячи - это мы тебе оставим в качестве домашнего задания.

Comment: В доту на уроках не играют: большой разброс длительности партии мешает уложиться в 45 минут. К тому же дота требует много активности - её так просто не свернуть когда учитель подходит.

Comment: Всегда приятно получить комментарий эксперта 